# Get screenshot of div with html2canvas and show the image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html2canvas

I've read all the topics about html2canvas and I still don't get it. I have only 1 div with a content that I wanna convert to the image and 1 "PrintScreen" button that should do it. So how to do it? I tried almost every snippet I found and still nothing... Any help would be great and appreciated!

Comment: Show us something you've tried

Comment: `var canvasRecord = $('body').html2canvas();
 
var dataURL = canvasRecord.toDataURL("image/png");`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by putting this in the  section of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function setUp(){
   h2cSelector = '#bar';
 }      
</script>
```

Also you change check this [example](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/tests/origin.html)